# Why is the type for [tail, init, reverse], [[a] -> [a]]?

Tags: haskell

This question is in one of the Haskell textbook exercises, not so smart question.

Question: What are the types of the following values?

```
[tail, init, reverse]
```

Solution: `[[a] -> [a]]`

But why?

Answer (score 7):

`tail`, `init` and `reverse` are functions defined on a generic list, `[a]`. You read `[a]` as "a list of any type abstracted as `a`", in particular, if `a = Int`, you get `[Int]` - list of integers.

Now, function that takes a list and outputs a list of the same type has signature `[c] -> [c]` or, if `c = a`, `[a] -> [a]`. The letter picked up does not matter as long as you have the same latter on both sides, because `[a] -> [b]` would mean that you take somehow a list of `a`s and **map** it to a list of `b`s - which - in general - a different type. You could say that `a = Int` and `b = String` and therefore you'd have to map `Int` to `String` anyhow; also you could say that `b = a` an thus reduce to the `[a] -> [a]` case.

The last one: `[tail, init, reverse]` is obviously yet another list, where `a = [b] -> [b]`. So you got `[ [b] -> [b] ]` type or, equivalently, `[ [a] -> [a] ]` or `[ [k] -> [k] ]`. Again: particular letter does not matter as long as you stick to the chosen one.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the following ***value***, not "values". *singular*.  List of three elements is a value. Or did you mean "each of the values in the given list"? then they all must have the same type. since a list has a type `[t]` for some `t`. which implies all its elements have that same type `t`, whatever that is. then since `tail :: [a] -> [a]`, so must be the other two that appear in the same list.

On their own they could each refer to a different letter i.e. "type variable". but inside the same list, they all must be in agreement. thus the type of the list as a whole is `[ [a] -> [a] ]`.